# Understanding Sturm's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, roots

I am having trouble understanding why the [Sturm theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) works. I understand how to calculate a Sturm sequence.

However, I haven't got a clue how the change of signs of the polynomials in the sturm sequence at the boundary of $[a,b]$ is related to the number of zeros of $f$ in this interval. How can this feel natural?

**Addendum:**

[The Spanish Wikipedia article on the Sturm theorem](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teorema_de_Sturm) features some images explaining the theorem. This helped me a little. Maybe someone can make more out if it than I can.

Comment: It seems you tried to attach an article to Sturm's theorem but it hasn't come yet.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question.

Comment: Good to know. I'm just a little bit on the edge of the word "natural" because it's a bit vague, but if I understand correctly you are basically trying to look for ways to correlate the change of signs with the number of zeros mathematically. Let me see if I can be of assistance.

Comment: I'm trying to grasp the "intuition" (if there is any) behind it.

Comment: Sure, I'll see what assistance I can offer you.

Comment: For Spanish readers: The Spanish Wikipedia article on the Sturm theorem features some images explaining the theorem. This helped me a little. Maybe someone can make more out if it than I can. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teorema_de_Sturm

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks. I will try to be even more specific, I cannot believe learning Spanish some days ago would prove mildly beneficial. While I try to write something up, you can attach this link to your question post as well, it's a useful comment and counts as context.

Comment: Are you still working on an answer? Should I extend the bounty? It'll expire tomorrow.

Comment: I will complete my answer within 5-6 hours from now, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the main idea behind Sturm's theorem is very simple. The idea is the recurrence (in the Spanish Wikipedia page [here](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teorema_de_Sturm) (note : translate to English, the translation is decent, or test your Spanish out!) given by :
$$
f_{n+1}(x) = q_nf_{n}(x) - f_{n-1}(x)
$$
where $f_{n+1},f_n,f_{n-1}$ are polynomials with $f_{n+1}$ being the remainder when $f_{n+1}$ is divided by $f_n$. This recurrence alone does all the "natural" lifting that the Sturm lemma requires. Why? Because in one shot, this recurrence establishes some properties between the roots of $f_{n+1},f_n, f_{n-1}$, *and* the behaviour of these functions in intervals around those roots. Let me quickly explain all the lifting this recurrence does.

- *The root transfer property* :  Let $\alpha$ be a root that is common to both $f_{m}$ and $f_{m-1}$ for some $m$. Then, it will be a root of $f_{m-2}$ as well, because of the recurrence. Then it's a root of $f_{m-1}$ and $f_{m-2}$ as well, and therefore of $f_{m-3}$.

  - Like this, the root gets "carried" to become a root of all $f_k$ for $k \leq m$, IF it is a root of $f_{m}$ and $f_{m-1}$. In particular, every $\alpha$ that is a root of both $f_{m}$ and $f_{m-1}$ for some $m$, will also be a root of $f_0$. Thus, the nature of the final $f$ is important.
  - BUT : Because the degrees of $f$ are decreasing, the last $f$ will in fact be some polynomial of small degree, that will be easy to spot and factorize. This way, what happens is that *multiple roots* of the sequence are reflected in the final $f$. This is important.
  - The roots also get carried *UP* : because $f_{m+1} = q_mf_m - f_{m-1}$, the root $\alpha$ will also be a root of $f_{m+1}$, then similarly of $f_{m+2}$ and so on. So at the end of all this : *a root common to consecutive functions is common to all the functions*.
- The *sign-reversal* property : Let $\alpha$ be a root of $f_n$. Then, at $\alpha$, we have $f_n(\alpha) = 0$ so $f_{n+1}(\alpha) = -f_{n-1}(\alpha)$. This is sign-reversal : the sign at the root of $f_n$ being opposite for $f_{n+1}$ and $f_{n-1}$.   (Or both are zero, in which case we come back to the zero carrying property).

These properties are the two *KEY* properties that come from the recurrence relation. The root transfer property, and the sign reversal property. Let us now see what happens.

---

Now, we go back to our choice of *first* functions for the Sturm theorem i.e. recall that $f_{n}(x) = p(x)$ and $f_{n-1}(x) = p'(x)$, the derivative of $x$. Furthermore, we assumed that $p(x)$ is a polynomial that has only *simple* roots i.e. roots with multiplicity $1$. That is, for no real $\alpha$ does $(x-\alpha)^2$ divide $p(x)$.

But, this property dovetails with the root transfer and the sign-reversal property beautifully :

- If $p$ is a polynomial with only simple roots, then one can see that (1) $p$ and $p'$ don't have common roots and (2) between any two roots of $p$ lies a root of $p'$ (this follows from Rolle's theorem). Now, by using the root transfer property, we can see that *NO TWO* $f_{m},f_{m-1}$ can share a common root! Because if they did, then lifting up the root will tell us that $p$ and $p'$ have that root common as well, a contradiction! Hence, we've managed to use just the recurrence and derivative properties to get a sequence of polynomials such that no two consecutive polynomials can share a root.

  - Note that the last polynomial $f_0$ in the sequence will be a constant polynomial, but it cannot be the zero polynomial(why? Because then $f_0,f_1$ will share a root obviously!). So this polynomial is either positive or negative.
- Suppose that $\alpha$ is a root of $p$. Then, because $p'$ can't have a root there, this means that $p'$ is either greater than, or less than zero. But more importantly, it means that $p$ *changes sign* at $\alpha$, because the derivative's non-negativity will tell you that $p$ is either strictly increasing or decreasing in a neighbourhood of $\alpha$ and therefore must change sign at $\alpha$.

  - Furthermore, note that if $p'>0$ then $p$ is increasing so there's a $-$ to $+$ sign change, and if $p'<0$ then $p$ is decreasing so there's a $+$ to $-$ sign change any root. This means : roots of $p$ *link* to sign changes of $p$ by virtue of $p$ being simple, and the changes in sign are provided by the sign of the derivative at these points.

So what's happened, is that the fact that we started out with $p$ and $p'$ , and the fact that our recurrence is of a certain kind, give us very natural relations between the roots of various $f_i$ and the sign changes of these $f_i$ at roots of nearby $f_i$. All this will move very smoothly into gear when we see what happens when we look at the sign-sequence.

> The reason why we are looking at the change-in-sign sequence , is because let's say I take a sequence of signs like $+,-,+,+,-$ etc. *Now, if I change one sign, then the number of changes of sign will depend ONLY UPON the signs which are NEXT to it*. That's exactly why we have the two-term recurrence : to see how much one sign changing affects the change-in-sign count , you only need to observe it's neighbours. See how natural this feels now.

---

Let $\alpha$ be some real number. Now, what we are going to do is look at the sequence given by $p(\alpha),p'(\alpha), f_{n-2}(\alpha), f_{n-3}(\alpha),...,f_{0}(\alpha)$, and we are going to be looking for the number of sign-changes in this sequence, leaving zeros out. So for example, $1,0,-4,10$ has two sign changes. We call the number of changes as $\sigma(\alpha)$.

What we do, is move from left-to-right and then see what happens to $\sigma$.

- Suppose that $\alpha$ is *NOT* a root of any of the $f_i$. Then, by continuity, none of the $f_i$ have a root in a neighbourhood of $\alpha$ so $\sigma(\alpha)$ is constant in a neighbourhood of $\alpha$.
- Suppose that $\alpha$ is a root of , say $f_m$ for $n>m>0$. Then, we know that $\alpha$ is not a root of either $f_{m-1}$ OR $f_{m+1}$, and therefore in a neighbourhood of $\alpha$, the signs of these quantities remain constant and opposite to each other. Thus, in a neighbourhood of $\alpha$, the sign sequence at $m+1,m,m-1$ either reads like $+,-,-$ or $+,+,-$ or $-,-,+$ or $-,+,+$. So the sign change across this part is the same for all these combinations i.e. one sign change, in a neighbourhood of $\alpha$. Furthermore, even if $\alpha$ is a root of two common $f_i,f_j$ then they will have separate $+,-,-$-type blocks on which the sign change remains $1$ throughout a neighbourhood of $\alpha$.

  - The upshot of all this, is that $\sigma$ *doesn't change* at a root of $f_m$!
- Suppose $\alpha$ is a root of $p$. Then, obviously $\alpha$ is not a root of $p'$ so the sign for $p$ flips but that for $p'$ stays constant, so the number of sign-changes increases by $1$!

If you notice the above, we have shown that:

> $\sigma(x)$ increases by $1$ at every root $x$ of $p$, and is constant elsewhere.

Therefore, the number of roots of $p$ in $[a,b]$ is obviously given by $\sigma(b) - \sigma(a)$.

Now, you may hopefully understand the Sturm algorithm better. I will edit this question to present a generalization, but this I will keep for later.

---

Key points :

- The recurrence giving root-transfer and sign-reversal properties.
- The derivative properties and simplicity linking sign-changes to roots further.
- The idea that sign-changes and the two-term recurrence go together very well (see the highlighted box).
- The final proof where everything comes together splendidly.

I used [this](https://www.imsc.res.in/%7Eknr/past/sturm/formal_notes.pdf) as a reference as well, but I'll hopefully have time to put in the generalization as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really like the phrasing of your answer and that you gave names to certain properties. I will need time to digest this answer though. Perhaps, I will ask a question re-reading your answer and thinking through it.

Comment: I suppose you meant that $f_{n+1}$ is the remainder after dividing $f_{n-1}$ by $f_n$, right?

Comment: Concerning the root inheritance in the chain: I though that $f_0$, i. e. the last polynomial in the Sturm sequence will be a constant function; thus having no roots. (and you say that yourself in the answer). However, your second bullet point claims that if $f_m$ and $f_{m-1}$ have a common root, it'll also be a root of $f_0$.

Comment: @Analysis Exactly, that is also a proof of contradiction, of the fact that no two of $f_m$ and $f_{m-1}$ can have a common root.